# Echo content based on current tabbed page in theme options

Tags: theme-options

How I can echo some content based on current tab in my theme options. My tabbed theme option page has these tabs TAB1, TAB2, TAB3

I want to display a message on TAB2. The theme options page slug is /`wp-admin/admin.php?page=options&tab=tab_1`

I tried with

```
function show_message(){

if( isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ? $_GET['tab'] : 'tab_2' ){
echo 'This message';
else{
echo 'That Message';
}
}
add_action('admin_head','show_message');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP logic is slightly off - you need to check the *value* of `$_GET['tab']`. At the moment you're saying "if `$_GET['tab']` or `'tab_2'`", which will always evaluate true:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['tab'] ) && $_GET['tab'] === 'tab_2' )
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not also help.. I also tried with this with no luck

if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'options' && isset( $_GET['tab'] ) && $_GET['tab'] === 'tab_2' ){

Comment: Use the hook `admin_notices` instead of `admin_head`

Comment: :( did not help.I think I am not getting the current screen of the the targeted tab.